# Exercise about a limit with greatest integer function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

> Let:
>
> $$f(x) := \begin{cases} x+3 &\text{, if } x\in (-2,0) \\ 4 &\text{, if } x=0 \\ 2x+5 &\text{, if } 0<x<1\end{cases}\;.$$
>
> Then find $\lim_{x\to 0^-} f([x-\tan x])$, where $[\cdot]$ is greatest integer.

Since $x$ is approaching zero from the negative side, $x>\tan x$

Therefore $[x-\tan x] =0$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}f( [x-\tan x])=[x+\tan x] +3 =3$$

But the right answer is 4.

Basically,  I am having a problem in choosing the right function for the given limit, because $f(x)=4$ for $x=0$, but $x$ actually isn’t 0, then how can it be the answer?

Comment: Q is not clear for me. Do you want to choose one of those functions so that the answer is $4$? Or calculate the limit for each choice of those functions?

Comment: Just a doubt: does the question clearly state that the symbol $[z]$ denotes the greatest integer function? Surely $\lim x\rightarrow 0^- \lfloor x - \tan x\rfloor=0$, but $\lim x\rightarrow 0^- \lceil x - \tan x\rceil=1$ and in this case the result would be $4$.

Comment: @VIVID I couldn’t figure out how to form vertical braces in LaTex, but that is how the question is

Comment: @Anatoly it is definitely greatest integer function,

Comment: Ok, if this is the case your answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $-\pi/2 < x < 0$ you have $\tan x < x < 0$, hence $x - \tan x > 0$. On the other hand, in a suitable left neighborhood $-\sigma < x <0$ of $0$ (with $\sigma > 0$), you have also $2x < \tan x$, therefore $x - \tan x < -2x$; moreover you can also choose $\sigma$ so small that $-2x < 1$. Thus $-\sigma < x < 0 \Rightarrow 0 < x - \tan x < 1$ and this entails $[x - \tan x] = 0$ everywhere in the small left neighborhood $]-\sigma , 0[$ of $0$.

Finally, you find:

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} f([x - \tan x]) = \lim_{x\to 0^-} f(0) = f(0)\; ,$$

therefore you have to check the text of your exercise: if $f(0) = 0$ as you wrote at the beginning, the answer is $0$; if $f(0) = 4$ as you wrote at the end, the answer is $4$. ;-)

Comment: How do you say:
$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} f([x - \tan x]) = f(0)$$ while $f$ is not continuous at $0$

Comment: @VIVID no, that equality is wrong as I explained before. And you cannot apply the chain rule to find the limit of the composition function because hypothesis of the theorem are not met; therefore all you can do is an explicit computation of the value of $f([x - \tan x])$.